# Are the quaternions a domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, quaternions

I have to give an example of a non-commutative domain that is not a division ring.  My first thought was $R = \big\{ a + bi + cj + dk \mid  a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Z} \big\}$ since $R$ is clearly non-commutative and not a division ring (take the number 2 for example).  I have seen conflicting accounts for if it is a domain though.  One source said it is since it is a subring of the quaternions.  However my book does not specify that quaternions are a domain, and I read a paper online that said that in fact they weren't a domain.  Then I read an answer on stack exchange from someone with a 62k rep that said the quaternions are a domain.  I tried proving it myself but I got stuck in a very long cycle.

Comment: It depends what you mean by "domain." Some require commutativity in the term. If all it means is that there are no zero divisors, then of course the quaternions form a domain, because they form a division ring.

Comment: Subrings of domains are domains, hence $R$ is a domain since $\mathbb{H}$ is a domain (being a division ring).

Comment: by a domain I mean that if $ab = 0$ then $a=0$ or $b=0$.

Comment: how does being a division ring imply a it is a domain

Comment: @Tim In a division ring, For each $a\neq 0$ there exists $a^{-1}$ such that $aa^{-1}=1$.  If $ab=0$, then either $b\neq 0$, or there is $b^{-1}$ with $0=0b^{-1}=abb^{-1}=a1=a$, showing that $a=0$.

Comment: Do you mean "integral domain"?

Comment: @Vim no..I edited this to reflect your comment below.  This question just wants a domain.

Comment: @Tim an integral domain requires commutativity but in $R$, $ij\ne ji$.

Comment: @Vim thanks..It has been noted in my brain!

Answer (score 4):

I think your confusion is coming from the fact that different authors use the word "domain" with different meanings.  In the context of your problem, "domain" clearly just means a (nonzero) ring in which $xy=0$ implies $x=0$ or $y=0$.  With that definition, any division ring is a domain (if $x\neq 0$ you can multiply $xy=0$ on the left by $x^{-1}$ to get that $y=0$), and since a subring of a domain is clearly a domain, it follows that $R$ is a domain.

On the other hand, some authors (especially those that think mainly about commutative rings) take "domain" to mean that in addition to the condition above, the ring is commutative.  With this definition, of course the quaternions are not a domain, because they are not commutative.

Comment: Ahhh yes I think that is why I was confused.  Thank you, I see it clearly now!